# printf/sprintf madness (spontanous concatenation)

Tags: c, printf, concatenation

I have a program that takes 2x24bit integer converts them to `strings` via `sprintf` and put them together to a string that represents a 58bit number.
Program:

```
int buffer_h = 0x001FFFFF;
int buffer_l = 0x002FFFFF;
int i,j = 0;

char res_h[10];
char res_l[10];
char res_all[12];

sprintf(res_h,"%06X",buffer_h);

sprintf(res_l,"%06X",buffer_l);

for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
    res_all[i] = res_h[i];
}

for(i=0;i<6;i++) {
    res_all[i+6] = res_l[i];
}

printf("%s",res_all);
```

You maybe think the output on `res_all` is `res_h+res_l` which are 6+6=12 characters so: `1FFFFF2FFFFF` but the output is: `1FFFFF2FFFFF2FFFFF`
if I shorten `res_all` to `res_all[6]` it's all right.

But how can a 6 character string be printed to a 18 character?

Comment: A nullchar terminator in `res_all` may improve your  chances of success *considerably*. That, and proper sizing of your buffers.

Comment: What @WhozCraig said. Alternatively, you can print a char buffer that isn't null-terminated by explicitly specifying a precision: `printf("%.12s", res_all);` (Making the string null terminated will allow it to be used with many standard functions, so that's the better approach.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to null terminate (`'\0'`)  `res_all`. `printf` only work deterministically on null terminated strings.  I am guessing you got lucky and `res_all` just happens to be located in memory directly before `res_l`, which happens to be null terminated. You could have just as easily been off in the weeds somewhere.

Comment: ...and your point is what exactly?

Comment: I could see how my answer could be interpreted that way. I did not mean to imply that '/0' == null. I simply meant you need to null terminate the string and '/0' is how you specify the null terminator.

Comment: Blah...yes that is what I meant...I have slash dyslexia.

Comment: "printf only work deterministically on null terminated strings." is not true.  Code could use `printf("%.12s",res_all);`.

Comment: What if the string and the buffer are less than 12 bytes  and the string is not null terminated?

Comment: A _string_ in C **always** has a null character at the end, else it is not a _string_ - so the question is a bit unclear.   `"%.12s"` will print the first 12 characters of a character array unless it encounters a null character, in which case it will stop.

Comment: My point is that printf("%.12s",res_all) is only deterministic if res_all is at least 12 bytes in length or it contains the null character.

Comment: Wow thank's to all! it works now :) Printf with %c is also working but not always.

Comment: I now accepted to write an string array one field longer because of the /0. The programming teacher was right about strings, even if she could fry a working program and change it's name to "(source filename)_better"